On what basis does a paper get accepted into a top journal?
Since the initial question was closed, but seems to be attracting a lot of discussion even after the fact, some of the comments qualifying as full answers IMO, I believe it is a reasonable question to ask. It has further recieved several upvotes.
Many younger mathematicians I know have also said that they want this information to be readily accessible, as it is important information for their careers. The site has a career tag specifically for questions like this.
The arguments for and against why it is a reasonable question are well summarised in the comments of the original post, so I will not repeat them.
Question:
Publishing in a top generalist journal like the Annals of Mathematics, Inventiones, or a similar tiered journal is considered to be a major achievement in mathematics. Many young mathematicians seem to mention publishing in a journal of that ranking as a major career goal.
How does one determine when a result is significant enough to submit to an top journal, and have it not be a long shot to be accepted? What are some key aspects that one should look for in a result of that caliber?
Update: The answers are surprising, to say the least. If anything I should be complaining the least, since I am a probablist/stochastic analyst by hours spent, and probability, especially stochastic analysis is getting its time in the spotlight. But I do not like this state of affairs, and I think it is counterproductive for mathematics as a whole.

You shouldn't just post the same question again after it got closed.

@Sam Hopkins According to the site guidelines, I should either make a new post and/or edit the original post to be a more reasonable question. I have edited it appropriately according to YCor’s suggestions.

I believe it is now a reasonable question as posed.

How is this not a question about research-level mathematics? I for one have learned that only certain branches of math are worthy of the top accolades.

I have been informed that this is how academia works. @Nemo

@NateRiver I repeat my comment here: if this question is meant to replace the old one, the old one should be deleted. It would be better if you self-delete rather than have other people (or a mod) do it for you.

@DavidRoberts Could the comments from the old question be kept even if the question is deleted (eg in a chatroom)? I think that discussion is excellent and ought not to be deleted.

https://academia.stackexchange.com/

@Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda well, anyone is welcome to copy and paste the comments and host them somewhere. I would have to ask about how chatroom comments survive (or not) the deletion of their parent question.

Now the old question is deleted, only 10k+ reputation users can still see it. I repeat that if anyone in that position is so moved, they can copy the comments for hosting elsewhere.

@Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda see here for the comment thread on the now-deleted original question: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/154515/discussion-on-question-by-nate-river-on-what-basis-is-a-paper-accepted-into-a-to

@DavidRoberts Sorry, was away from the computer for awhile. I see the original closed thread is now deleted, so we may use this thread as the main one now.

I think this question is fine (and I certainly didn't vote to close the previous one), but it is not a good strategy to start a separate question with almost the same content.  A better approach is to improve the question and vote to re-open it.  One advantage of this is that the same people can't start trying to close your new question, because you can only vote to close a question once.

I don't know the answer to this question, but I certainly can tell you how to get a paper rejected from a top journal.

@GabeK What a sad state of affairs.

@GabeK That’s a very ominous comment. Tell me, why should any young person get into this wretched business?

@NateRiver I'm mostly joking, but there's a lot more to mathematics than publishing in the most selective journals. Doing so greatly improves job prospects, which is why it is so important early in one's career, but the vast majority of worthwhile research is not published in the top 5 journals.

@GabeK We both know it wouldn’t be a joke if I were posting under my real name.

I’m voting to close this question because it seems to have run its course, and the discussion is no longer particularly informative.

I second the vote to close the question.

@NateRiver Regarding why any young person get into this wretched business: Similar dysfunctionalities exist in any line of work. The problem is not academia per se, but human nature. Anyway, I have also voted to close.

I think it's mostly just vibes.

Here is a starting point, backed up with some data from mathscinet. My intended audience is a young mathematician who knows very little about the "top" journals.
There are five journals that are unambiguously "top" but actually some are more selective than others and have different biases. The journals are Inventiones Mathematicae, Journal of the AMS, Annals of Mathematics, Acta Mathematica and Publications Mathématiques. Institut de Hautes Études Scientifiques.
I wrote the journals in descending order of number of articles published per year.

Inventiones has been around since 1966 and since writing this has 4668 papers indexed by mathscinet. That is an average of 80 papers per year.

JAMS has been around 1988 and has 1074 papers for an average of 30 papers per year.

Annals has been around since 1911 and has 3072 papers for an average of 27 papers per year.

Acta has been around since 1882 and has 2197 papers for an average of 15 papers per year.

Publ. IHES has been around since 2001 and has 190 papers for an average of 8 papers per year. (According to mathscinet. According to zbmath, it is 524 papers since 1959 for an average of 8 papers a year again)


Even though these are the "top 5 journals," it is clear there is still a difference.
The next consideration is the area. According to mathscinet the top 3 areas in each journal are

Inventiones: algebraic geometry, number theory, several complex variables (all time). algebraic geometry, number theory and differential geometry (last 3 years).

JAMS: algebraic geometry, number theory, PDE (all time). algebraic geometry, differential geometry, number theory (last 3 years).

Annals: algebraic geometry, number theory, manifolds and cell complexes (all time). algebraic geometry, number theory, PDE (last 3 years).

Acta: functions of a complex variable, complex analysis, PDE (all time). Algebraic geometry, differential geometry, probability and stochastic processes (last 3 years).

Publ. IHES: algebraic geometry, global analysis/analysis on manifolds, manifolds and cell complexes (all time). algebraic geometry, differential geometry, number theory (last 3 years)


Notice that algebraic geometry and number theory are king when it comes to top 5 journals. Acta has a bit more analysis but still algebraic geometry is most popular in last 3 years.
Next I want to describe how the editorial process typically works at journals like this. First, the editor looks at the paper and determines if they want to send it out for quick opinions. Second, the editor sends it out for quick opinions (usually at least 2-3 but I know one case that had 20 quick opinions). The quick opinion approximates answering the question "if everything is right, is this paper worthy of publishing in this journal?" This is the phase where most papers get rejected. Third, they go out for full reports. Papers can still be rejected here but it is less common.
A few more observations:

Papers in top journals tend to be very long and quite involved. Often longer than 100 pages.

Papers that solve some famous/named conjecture tend to get published in top journals.

Some journals tend to publish on certain topics frequently, often depending on the editor (e.g. Inventiones has had a lot of regularity structures and percolation papers recently)


So what is my advice if you want to publish in a top journal?
First, you should follow the advice for writing any paper. Write the paper clearly and carefully. Choose an editor who will handle your paper fairly. Write an introduction that clearly lays out why your paper is good, etc.
For top 5 journals in particular you should write a paper in the right area (likely algebraic geometry or number theory), send your paper to the right journal among the top 5. Also, your paper likely should be quite long and technical/involved. If your proof doesn't use sophisticated techniques then it likely won't make it into a top 5 journal. Also, it helps to prove an established open conjecture.
Also, you should write your paper in a way so that it reads well for a quick opinion. That means you should clearly establish your main theorems and make obvious their importance. Highlight difficult or interesting parts of the proof clearly. Your paper won't be judged based on a full reading, and your paper will likely be very long and involved, so the important parts should be very clear.
One nice thing about choosing to submit to top 5 journals is rejections tend to happen quickly (within 3 months) during the quick opinion phase. So there is often not much cost to submitting there. I also recommend not sending every paper to a top 5 journal first to maintain your reputation, only your best work.

What a pity that these supposedly top generalist journals are apparently so narrow. Perhaps I should start advising my students to switch to algebraic geometry or number theory, if they ever want to be real mathematicians.

@JoelDavidHamkins It is indeed sad. I of course wish generalist journals more accurately represented the areas that mathematicians actually work on. I checked and there were 3 papers listed under logic in the last 3 years in Annals. I am confident there is more than 1 very strong logic paper per year...

This paper seems relevant: Topical Bias in Generalist Mathematical Journals. See also Information about publishing and citations.

You say "it is clear there is still a difference". I agree that there is a difference in the number of papers they publish annually, but this does not mean there is a similar difference in the quality of papers they publish. For example, I could start a journal where I accept 5 random papers per year (if I get at least 5 manuscripts). Does that mean that I created a journal stronger than Publ IHES?

It is sad. I am working on an area which, according to two mathematicians who works on the same area, "is attracting less and less attention these days". And yet, some universities (only) look at impact factor for appointment and promotion.

I am not disagreeing with your findings, that algebraic geometry is probably overrepresented, but I am not sure how significant looking at the top 3 areas is without normalizing them in some way (e.g. I am not surprised to see PDE in that list, as it is one of the largest fields) and without giving discussing the size of the tail (e.g. are most of the articles in the top 3, or are there just slightly more than for place 4 and so on).

@JoelDavidHamkins The narrowness of the supposedly top journals is probably due at least in part to self-selection. For example, you said yourself that you don't submit to them, so it's impossible for them to publish your papers. If you think that this is a "pity" then one thing you could do is start submitting to them. Or to put it another way, if having logic and set theory papers published in these journals is not important, then why is it a "pity"?

@TimothyChow The pity is that so many people seem to think of these journals as "generalist" and also that they are a reliable judge of quality across mathematics. Since I am also predisposed against journal rankings generally, finding them harmful to the subject, I would prefer that we judge the papers themselves (journal impact factors, for instance, are now completely discredited as a reliable means of judging quality of individual articles). I don't feel compelled to help out the Annals. I also disagree with your suggestion below that logic has some kind of prestige problem to solve.

The nature of the question differs for people who have already established a publication record versus people who are writing their first few papers. Once a publication record is established, then a good guide is that you should only submit a paper to one of the top journals if and only if you feel the new paper is better than all of the papers you have published in lower-ranked journals. Of course, this is empty advice for new researchers submitting their first three papers, say.
In that case, one has to discuss what I consider to be the "underbelly" of research publishing, something "dirty" that practically every researcher knows of and has to contend with but hardly anyone wants to go on the record to say anything about it. It is most certainly true that there are things beyond merit at play when papers get judged. I would say that for most early career researchers, especially those without significant patronage networks (many people don't even know they are in such networks, while others apply to certain schools/institutions with the explicit intent of being a part of such networks) backing them, one should not try to submit to the very top journals unless the result is truly groundbreaking and cannot be dismissed as unimportant even by the most ruthless referee. A good barometer I use for myself is that the problem should have its own Wikipedia page.

I certainly agree with your first paragraph, but perhaps less with your second, and in particular with your final sentence. There are groundbreaking papers that do not "solve a problem" but create new mathematical tools and theories. Of course, you clearly stated that this is a barometer that you use for yourself, so it's hard to disagree with that ;-)

I would say if you don’t consider your work to be “truly groundbreaking” then submitting to a top journal is quite risky, but of course it doesn’t hurt to try as the first answer stated. People have certainly “gotten lucky” in that regard. Further, even top journals have a bottom 25 percentile of papers that are mostly forgettable.

And then there are people who apparently had the backing of the establishment even though essentially everything interesting they've published is wrong. There is one particular author I'm thinking of who shall remain nameless, with papers in the Annals, Inventiones, and Advances, all with errata basically saying the paper is irretrievable. This author gave up maths and is now a politician.

@DaveBenson:  You have dangerous initials.

@DaveBenson: In my opinion, that author's greatest accomplishment is publishing a totally wrong paper in the American Mathematical Monthly.  If I were an unethical person, I could imagine ways to sneak something wrong into the Annals, but the Monthly seems like a much harder nut to crack.

I find it fascinating that most of the errors in the aforementioned papers, whose author remains stubbornly nameless in spite of the initials, amount to a single rather rookie mistake, amazingly well hidden. If a topological space is a union of two contractible subsets with contractible intersection, then it's contractible. A nice pub quiz question (they have strange pubs around here) is to find an easy and totally ordinary counterexample with no pathologies of any kind.

@DaveBenson It should be pointed out that said nameless author left mathematics for politics quite some time before the errors in the papers were discovered, or at least before the errors were made public.

Somehow I am reminded of this post by Tao. The unsightly sides of academia are now just slightly more common knowledge.

Since true statements are not defamatory in the USA or my own country of residence, I don't see why I shouldn't name Daniel Biss. One of the errors was noticed in this question.

@StanleyYaoXiao As a relative newcomer to the world of “professional mathematics”, let me say this isn’t a good look for mathematics academia at all. Every researcher knows, and every researcher is silent? The whole thing feels rotten to the core.

I can’t even begin to express my disappointment that this is what I’m getting into if I continue with academic mathematics.

@NateRiver I am sorry that this is what you got out of my post; that was certainly not my intention. I guess if you want a pure meritocracy then mathematics fails at that. Any profession made up of people will form cliques and dynamics of power and politics will be at play. I would say that in the grand scheme of things, mathematics is a fairly good approximation to the ideals of academia, at least as good as any other profession.

@StanleyYaoXiao Yeah there are weak, small minded people in every profession I guess.

What I got from the post, and the public perception of journals is that research math is a podium contest, and the top spots are reserved.

@NateRiver I don't think it is fair to attribute the general phenomenon to "weak, small minded people". It is rather more harmless: everyone has their own tastes and preferences, even when it comes to mathematicians, and senior ones at that. The problem is that overtime groups of like-minded people, all with similar tastes and preferences, can dominate the top echelons of certain institutions, leading to biases.

@StanleyYaoXiao I agree with your analysis. Although, I think the reason people often don't bother to state explicitly that "things beyond merit" play a factor is that it is so obviously true that only a mathematician could think it's not obvious. But even a mathematician should be able to recognize that it's impossible to give a mathematically rigorous definition of the word "merit."

@StanleyYaoXiao It feels dishonest to pretend that only harmless cliques that form naturally exist, instead of “mafias” as I referred to in my other comment that form and are maintained unnaturally.

Especially since your last paragraph seems to imply that if a biased editor wants a beneficiary of theirs to be published, they will do everything they can to get your paper rejected in favour of the beneficiary.

… and Gabe K’s comment seems to imply that an editor with a grudge against you will also do the same.

@NateRiver There are well-known cases, very famous ones at that, where an editor who is a powerful mathematician have rammed through papers by their proteges (sometimes themselves!) through the publication process for fame and fortune, so it is not even hypothetical that this happens. That said, this is very rare and should not be considered normal or average behaviour. Most mathematicians are good actors.

@StanleyYaoXiao But your last paragraph implies that none of the top 5 journals are definitively safe.

@NateRiver I believe your interpretation is correct.

@NateRiver If Diogenes were alive today, he might carry a lantern looking for a venue that is "definitively safe."

@TimothyChow Maybe so, but I think as someone without any publication record or patronage networks, one should indeed follow the advice in the post. I think that is a healthy level of skepticism.

DB's error(s) were made public in 2007, yet conveniently ignored for years, see: https://arxiv.org/abs/0709.1291

@NateRiver My comment was intended as a joke that I have expertise getting my work rejected. I didn't mean to imply that editors hold grudges. I presume it can happen, but the vast majority of rejections are because the editors and referees do not feel that the paper is significant or exciting enough. There's a fair amount of subjectivity to it, but it is reasonable to expect a math paper in a top journal to make a novel and substantial contribution.

I still don't think this is a good question for MO. But I want to push back against the idea, repeated here in multiple places, that top journals ignore some areas of math and are biased in some fundamental way.
Let me just focus on one top journal, the Annals of Mathematics, because of the central place it occupies in the discourse, and one area of math, combinatorics, because it is my area.
In 2012 Igor Pak wrote a blog post How do you solve a problem like the Annals? where he discussed the perceived bias against combinatorics that the Annals has. As evidence for this bias, he pointed out that up until the time he wrote that post, there were only 18 total papers ever published in the Annals with Primary MSC 05, according to MathSciNet, and we can easily reproduce that query to verify his claim. This total is much less than other areas of math like number theory.
However, even at that time, Pak noted that the Annals appeared increasingly more willing to publish combinatorics papers, and his suggestion was for people working in combinatorics to submit their very good papers to top journals like the Annals. And indeed, in 2024, we can do another query on MathSciNet to see that since 2012 there have been 18 papers with Primary MSC 05 published in the Annals. As mentioned, this is equal to the total amount before 2012. (And this query actually misses some papers I would consider firmly in combinatorics like this one by Petter Brändén and June Huh.)
So apparently the "bias" of the Annals against combinatorics has significantly decreased over time. I would say this is likely due to the efforts of combinatorialists to have their work appreciated.
All this is to say that of course the selection of papers which appears in any journal, top or not, depends in some way on the subjective opinions (and potential "biases") of its editors. But by and large people working in any area have the chance to have their work appreciated, as long as their work is really excellent and they do a good job communicating it. Now, as for what makes good mathematics, that is another question, but maybe I can direct you to the classic article by Terry Tao on that subject.

Thanks for this post. It is indeed not true that Annals ignores areas of math, and most areas are at least somewhat represented. Additionally, things like algebraic geometry touch on more areas so hence are more represented, even if only incidentally. I don't think there is some conspiracy and I am glad you say this.

For comparison, according to the search   j:("Ann. of Math.") AND pc:(03) y:[0 2024]   the Annals has published a grand total of 24 papers in logic, altogether since its inception (probably this misses papers that don't use the MSC). Logic is a huge field with more than a dozen of its own specialist journals, its own professional societies, and deep connections with essentially all parts of mathematics, and also deep connections with neighboring areas such as theoretical computer science.

Meanwhile, 351 papers with pc:15 (algebraic geometry), and 311 papers with pc:11 (number theory).

@JoelDavidHamkins We're getting into exactly the kind of opinion-based argumentation which makes this question a bad fit for MO, but: how would you demonstrate that research in logic is having a profound impact on contemporary mathematics, especially compared to other areas? One way of course would be to show off the logic papers published in the top journals, but the allegation I guess is that the top journals are biased against logic. We could look at the most prestigious prizes. Paul Cohen won the Fields Medal in 1966, but no logician has won it since then, and none ever won the Abel Prize.

I'm not complaining about bias. Rather, my complaint is that the Annals just isn't important for all subjects. In logic, it is nearly irrelevant. (Perhaps it is because of historical lack of knowledge of logic by other mathematicians and journals that caused logic to develop its own journals and societies, and so there basically isn't a culture of publishing in the supposedly generalist journals.) There are over 80,000 articles on MathSciNet with subject code 03, but only 24 of them are in the Annals. To me, that failure reflects more on the Annals than it does on logic as a subject.

According to MathSciNet, Saharon Shelah alone has published 5 papers in the Annals. I wouldn't say that's irrelevant.

Are you seriously suggesting that the logic numbers in the Annals are accurately reflecting the contribution of logic to mathematics? I would find that absurd.

No, I'm not saying that at all. My focus is on the question that Nate River posed, what advice would you give to a young mathematician looking to get their papers in the top journals. Although you haven't said exactly this, I take it your advice might be: if you're working in logic, ignore the so-called "top journals" like the Annals. But maybe a different response would be: try to get your very best work in these general journals which have a lot of prestige, it is possible.

Yes, that in fact is the advice I give. We talk mainly about the logic journals and which ones might be suitable for their work; the other journals just don't matter that much. Personally, though I have over 100 published articles, I haven't ever submitted a paper to Annals or any of the other journals being mentioned here as top 5 or whatever. It just hasn't seemed important.

the Annals has published a grand total of 24 papers in logic... 351 papers with pc:15 (algebraic geometry), and 311 papers with pc:11 (number theory) - How do those numbers compare with the total number of papers per field?

@JoelDavidHamkins A possible argument for encouraging "top" logicians to publish in the allegedly "top" journals is this: Doing so will likely increase the prestige of logic as a field, and improve the incentives for junior mathematicians to work in logic. The whole "prestige game" may be absurd and distasteful, but it remains a fact of life that junior mathematicians have to contend with. So senior logicians who work to increase the prestige of their subject are performing a service to junior logicians.

@TimothyChow Indeed. Long term we should work on moving to a more “flat” system. The number of implicit “tiers” within math journals is ridiculous. Journal of Applied Probability < Electronic Journal of Probability < Annals of Probability < Annals of Mathematics. Depending on how important your probability result is, it goes into one of these. How the hell am I supposed to decide? What even is an EJP tier, but not AoP tier result? And it is doubly hard because no one seems to want to give guidance publically. The art is too “dirty” for most people to even speak it seems.

@user479223 Let’s be honest. That is not the only reason why AG and NT are heavily over represented in the top journals. There are “cliques” that naturally form due to probablistic processes. And then there are “mafias” that form and are maintained unnaturally. And every researcher knows this. Both scenarios are counterproductive to ensuring that good math from all fields gets published.

Here is a similar story. I know of a friend that works on an area in geometry and he has a good publication record (several papers published in some very top journals in his field, but not the top five journals listed above). He once submitted a paper to a very top journal, but got rejected. The point is, he got some very bad comments. He then submitted his paper to another very top journal in his field, got accepted with some nice comments. The (editors of the) very top journal rejected his paper is known to have a very serious bias against other fields in geometry.

(continuing with my previous comments) I once met some students, who are professors at a university, of some of the editors of that very top journal some time ago. I can confirm that they have serious bias against any other fields (but not theirs) in geometry.

@NateRiver I wholeheartedly agree with you. The mafias do not only exist as editors of top journals, but also as professors in some top universities. My personal experience is if I am not in their circle, I am nothing to them.

@Kimball I game some numbers already, but you can do the search query at MathSciNet yourself with:    j:("Ann. of Math.") AND pc:(xx) y:[0 2024] and replace xx with your desired MSC code.

@TimothyChow I think there are reasons beyond the "prestige game" too. It's good to have a field be looked at and evaluated by outsiders. If mathematicians in your field only ever publish in field-specific journals, there is a risk the field becomes insular.

@NateRiver The point of my post was to push back against the idea that math research at the highest level is dominated by cabals. And I say this as someone who has never had a paper in a top journal and likely never will. I think the current systems, while imperfect like anything in this world, do a good job highlighting the best math. Life is full of many unfairnesses, starting with the random circumstances of our births. With the huge caveat aside that these unfairnesses of course feed into things, I've found academia to be very meritocratic compared to almost any other facet of society.

@SamHopkins You have more than enough power and say to fix this particular instance of unfairness here.

@NateRiver I don't understand your last comment. At any rate, I've said my piece here and indeed this question is devolving into the kind of Internet forum debate that I think is very unhealthy for MathOverflow.

@NateRiver I doubt that a "flat" system will ever be possible. Taking a step back for a minute, it's somewhat amazing that anyone gets paid for doing non-applied research at all. From an economic point of view, funding for pure math is a scarce resource, so people are going to compete for it, and some people will be better competitors than others. The invisible hand of economics is very powerful, and attempts to impose "justice" by fiat will always be fighting an uphill battle IMO.

When I was a grad student I was lamenting about "the state of academia" to my adviser who responded by "I don't give a f*ck about academia, I care about people. It is my job to help people. When I accepted you as a student I took on an obligation to help and support you. I don't care about academia, I care about you. Tell me what you want and I will try my best to help you achieve it, and I am a smart guy." I don't think I complained about "the state of academia" in the same way again.

@user479223 No wonder all the grad students I know are depressed.

@JoelDavidHamkins For what it's worth I think you are dramatically undercounting the number of papers in logic which have been published in the Annals. This search on zentralblatt turns up 65 entries, but a spot check suggests that's still a vast underestimate. Looking directly at the volumes of Annals published in 1966 (the earliest year available on their website) gives 5 papers related to logic: two papers on isols, two on decidability of word problems and finally, one of the seminal papers of Ax and Kochen.

@PatrickLutz: Indeed I think the MathSciNet database is only reliable, at least for these MSC searches, back to the 80s.

@JoelDavidHamkins Looking at other years in the 1960s suggests that 1966 was not particularly anomalous. So I would guess that at least something like 40 papers in logic were published in the Annals during the 1960s. To be fair, I do have the vague impression that the Annals published far more logic papers in the 1960s than they do today.

@Kimball Searching zentralblatt and arxiv both suggest that while algebraic geometry and number theory are somewhat bigger fields than logic, they are not vastly bigger. For example, according to zentralblatt, in 2015 there were about 3,605 logic papers published compared to about 4,824 in number theory. On arxiv, math.LO had 20 papers posted in the last week while math.NT had 70.

@Kimball I believe the discrepancy between zentralblatt and arxiv here may be partly because logic includes both mathematical logic as well as logic in philosophy and in computer science. Zentralblatt is probably catching at least some of these latter two categories while math.LO on arxiv does not (e.g. logic in computer science papers would be posted under cs.LO).

@PatrickLutz Yes, I had said in my first comment that my search only catches the papers using MSC code 03. But this was the same method used for the AG and NT numbers in the posted answers, so it seems a good way to compare. I expect that these searches miss many papers, but much less so with recent papers, which generally do use the codes, and for these years you have to admit the numbers are bad.

@JoelDavidHamkins I agree that your searches may be more accurate for the past couple decades (though it troubles me that it's so different from zentralblatt's numbers) and that this is perhaps not a bad first approximation for comparing logic and number theory (though I would want to do a much more careful search before making any strong claims about it). I also don't think anyone can deny that in recent decades, far more number theory and algebraic geometry papers have been published in the Annals than logic papers.

@JoelDavidHamkins However, I think your original comment does not give a correct impression of how many logic papers have been published in the Annals. I realize you acknowledged that your search might have missed some papers, but I would guess that the number you cited is off by at least a factor of 10 which seems pretty huge. I was mainly trying to correct this possible misimpression, not comment on the larger argument going on in this comments section.

@PatrickLutz Thank you, I think that's right. So let's consider just since 2000, the last 25 years, by which time I think the use of MSC is nearly universal, especially in Annals papers. Since that time, there have been 14 logic papers in Annals, 139 algebraic geometry papers, and 219 number theory papers.

@JoelDavidHamkins Those numbers sound pretty believable to me. I would guess that JAMS is slightly more favorable to logic and Inventiones slightly less so (compared to Annals). I agree with the overall point that, compared to algebraic geometry or number theory, logic is underrepresented in top generalist journals compared to its representation among mathematicians overall.

My argument is that we should stop describing them as generalist journals. Annals seems to be basically an algebraic geometry/number theory journal that sometimes publishes articles in other areas, but only rarely in logic and combinatorics (and presumably other neglected areas).

@FrancoisZiegler What is the proportion for more recent papers? Spot checking suggests that it is far higher than 10%.

@JoelDavidHamkins I think you are exaggerating with “basically algebraic geometry/number theory”. Since zbmath assigns MSC (c.1970) one finds Number theory 19.4%, Algebraic geometry 18.8%, Differential geometry 12.7%, Manifolds 12%, Ergodic theory 11.3%, Several complex variables 10%, PDE 8.8%, Lie groups 8.4%, Group theory 8.3%, Global analysis 8.2%, Complex analysis 5.2%, Functional analysis 4.7%, Algebraic topology 4.6%, Euclidean harmonic analysis 3.5%, Combinatorics 3.3%, Operator theory 3.2%, Probability 2.9%, Integration 2.8%, Logic 2.3%, etc.

@Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda I amended my previous comment since zbmath doesn’t systematically assign MSC before about 1970. You may adjust the link to find more recent proportions (which indeed climb for the top two fields; still they only account for about half).

Note that the percentages in @FrancoisZiegler's comment already add up to 150%, so we see that many papers are listed in more than one area. For example, close to one third of number theory papers (6.0 percentage points) are also counted under algebraic geometry. Likewise, differential geometry shares 3.1 percentage points with global analysis and 2.4 with manifolds. So you cannot simply add the percentages.

@HoMan-Ho one of the most shocking things I’ve learned in my career is that even very senior and highly distinguished researchers have to deal with special interests and agendas behind the top journals. It is not an experience unique to early career researchers. In fact I would go as far to say that unless you have a Fields Medal or something comparable, you will have to deal with this kind of BS if you are considering publishing in the elite journals.

@StanleyYaoXiao Here is a story I know that kind of support what you said, not perhaps not in the way you expect. There is a paper published by the Annals that I feel is not worthy of publication in the Annals. That paper was previously rejected by one of the other top five journals listed above. The author(s) of that paper has some friendship with an editor of the Annals (who is no longer an editor now).

I feel inclined to contribute to the question, but in part so as to answer something else. Sorry if this out of line.
A question of importance to people with a permanent academic job, and hence of importance to people seeking one, is How does one learn to determine which of their results are significant enough to submit to a top journal, without losing their interest in mathematics?
As a grad student, I was convinced that landing a permanent job was the end goal of the absurd game of mathematics journals (which I found fun, at some point, oddly). It turned out I got caught in a never-ending sequence of further competitions (for advancement, for leaves, for bonuses, for recognition, etc.) which put the publication process ahead of the mathematics, to the point I was wondering where a result could be published before finding a proof. Despite getting a full professorship quite early, I often felt inadequate and lesser than owed to my rank and than my peers. Of course, everyone recognizes impostor syndrome in this, but even recognizing it does not suffice to cure it.
While I might very well go back to academia, it went to the point I took a leave of absence to train as an actuary. This helps me feel things differently but testifies to a heavy toll this publication shenanigans can have.
So, my answer is: whatever determines the acceptance in a top journal⁽¹⁾, the maths and your interest in it should go first. Try not to let the competition needed to get the job you seek print itself on you, do things because they interest you and not because they might land you a job---otherwise that very job could turn depressing instead of liberating. You are not your publication list, even when we, as a community, do an awful lot of efforts to let you believe that.
This matches my advice about whether one should take the next postdoc: do it if it's fun to you, not for the sole sake of landing a permanent job which may never come. So, do not hesitate to send to a top journal a result you are very proud of, but never take them too seriously; they do not deserve it, and even if they were completely objective and transparent, the whole thing is still built in a way that lets 99% of people feel subpar.
All this is easier said than done. While I do not always agree with Doron Zeilberger, I think reading his opinions can be a good way to detach oneself, emotionally at least, from the cult around these top journals. Talking to a therapist can help a lot more people than those who actually admit seeing one.
⁽¹⁾ As far as I understand, it all boils down to whether editors will get excited by the paper (possibly through the excitement of the quick opinions they ask if they are not bored right away). There are easy cases for acceptance (solving a well-known decades-old conjecture, although there are infamous counter-examples) and for rejection (your typical good-but-not-great paper, the kind which you can produce regularly---only applies to people who do not solve well-known conjectures regularly), but other than that, the composition of the (usually quite small) board determines what has more chance to get through.
Different fields have different publication habits and structure, e.g., in dynamical systems I have the feeling that the room available in top journals has increased, slightly decreasing the relative selectivity of top field-specific journals.
This answer is still very vague, but this is unavoidable. The whole publication process is very informal, with very little explicit policy, and very little accountability, but plays an incredibly central role in the organization of our community. I think this is at the core of the problem you raise, even before talking about cliques and mafias (which certainly do exist, at least to some extent). Even with the best will in the world, if you make a choice that obscure matter that strongly, you are doing something wrong. We are definitely doing something wrong.

+1 for the last paragraph. Many European universities make some attempt at transparency at the hiring stage (although universities often do whatever they want anyway), but for the publication process, there seems to be very little accountability. Quis custodiet ipsos custodes?
